# facebook oauth2 asp.net mvc 4

Tags: oauth-2.0

How to get *user profile image* and *email* ?
I tried to set values but did not get from `Extra Data`
Here is an example

```
            var fb = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            fb["scope"] = "email,user_birthday";
            fb ["Gender"] ="gender";
            fb["picture"] = "picture";
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
                appId: "244501199047737",
                appSecret: "48110451420dc5fc0c0a37ade08cdfe7", displayName: "facebook", extraData:fb);

AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl}));

        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
        string email = result.ExtraData["email"];
```

but can not  get user email from 
I get  error message:

**The given key was not present in the dictionary**

Comment: Maybe this answer help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680257/how-can-i-get-extradata-from-oauthwebsecurity#13594599][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680257/how-can-i-get-extradata-from-oauthwebsecurity#13594599